# Issue with the css on the svg

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg

Im having this issue , at the moment i have a really nice svg search, The issue is the div class col-md-10 is being weird. ITs only got a px height on 1px. (even though the svg is larger, Heres the image so you can see (i've done an inspect element and you can see the col-md-10)

[image]

Heres the code for the page

```
<div class="col-md-10">

  <div class="search">
    <svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 142.358 24.582">
    <path id="search-path" fill="none" d="M131.597,14.529c-1.487,1.487-3.542,2.407-5.811,2.407
        c-4.539,0-8.218-3.679-8.218-8.218s3.679-8.218,8.218-8.218c4.539,0,8.218,3.679,8.218,8.218
        C134.004,10.987,133.084,13.042,131.597,14.529c0,0,9.554,9.554,9.554,9.554H0"/>
    </svg>
    <label for="search" class="search-label"></label>
    <input type="search" id="search" autocomplete="off" class="input-search"/>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
/*
Inspired by Dribble "Search..."
  By: Anish Chandran
  Link: http://drbl.in/nRxe
*/

var searchField = $('.search');
var searchInput = $("input[type='search']");

var checkSearch = function(){
  var contents = searchInput.val();
  if(contents.length !== 0){
     searchField.addClass('full');
  } else {
     searchField.removeClass('full');
  }
};

$("input[type='search']").focus(function(){
  searchField.addClass('isActive');
}).blur(function(){
  searchField.removeClass('isActive');
  checkSearch();
});
</script>

</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <p color="white"> This is test text</p>
</div>
```

And the css for the svg is here

```
body {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -300px;
  width: 600px;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-246px);
  width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  stroke-width: 8px;
  stroke: #ED7710;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke-dasharray: 64.6 206.305;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}

.input-search {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 148px);
  height: 125px;
  top: 0;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.search-label {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 108px;
  height: 108px;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -54px;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.isActive .search-label {
  transform: translateX(246px);
}
.isActive svg {
  stroke-dashoffset: -65;
  stroke-dasharray: 141.305 65;
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.isActive.full svg {
  stroke-dashoffset: -65;
  stroke-dasharray: 141.305 65;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.full .search-label {
  transform: translateX(246px);
}
.full svg {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke-dasharray: 64.6 206.305;
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

Comment: Could you share the website please? If it is online

Comment: its localhost only sorry :(

Comment: try re-generate the issue on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: cant seem to get ti workign in a js fiddle either!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call your SVG like an image. For example with `<img src="yoursvg.svg" />`. It will still be svg, it's just within img tag. Give it a width and height if you need. When you call it with img tag it usually behaves really well, it's good for responsive also and you will not have weird behavior with bootstrap columns.

Then adjust javascript to do search stuff when someone clicks on img tag.

Hope this helps